# How to install a new Ruby version on Mac OS

Tags: ruby, xcode, installation, openssl, rbenv

I'm trying to install Ruby v2.7.0 on Mac OS Mojave v10.14.6 with rbenv by running `rbenv install 2.7.0` and I get the following error:

```
Downloading openssl-1.1.1d.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/1e3a91bc1f9dfce01af26026f856e064eab4c8ee0a8f457b5ae30b40b8b711f2
Installing openssl-1.1.1d...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.6 using ruby-build 20200224)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/qz/072qbsw163lb8p511v4dtssr0000gq/T/ruby-build.20200304000500.19560.8ElfaA
Results logged to /var/folders/qz/072qbsw163lb8p511v4dtssr0000gq/T/ruby-build.20200304000500.19560.log

Last 10 log lines:
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/bf_prefix.d.tmp -MT apps/bf_prefix.o -c -o apps/bf_prefix.o apps/bf_prefix.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/opt.d.tmp -MT apps/opt.o -c -o apps/opt.o apps/opt.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/s_cb.d.tmp -MT apps/s_cb.o -c -o apps/s_cb.o apps/s_cb.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/s_socket.d.tmp -MT apps/s_socket.o -c -o apps/s_socket.o apps/s_socket.c
ar r apps/libapps.a apps/app_rand.o apps/apps.o apps/bf_prefix.o apps/opt.o apps/s_cb.o apps/s_socket.o
ar: creating archive apps/libapps.a
/usr/local/Cellar/cctools/855/bin/ranlib: object: apps/libapps.a(app_rand.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
ar: internal ranlib command failed
make[1]: *** [apps/libapps.a] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The log file (`/var/folders/qz/072qbsw163lb8p511v4dtssr0000gq/T/ruby-build.20200304000500.19560.log`) looks like this:

```
/var/folders/qz/072qbsw163lb8p511v4dtssr0000gq/T/ruby-build.20200304000500.19560.8ElfaA ~/Documents/launch_school
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream
Content-Length: 8845861
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Oct 2019 21:38:26 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: AmazonS3
Date: Tue, 03 Mar 2020 02:47:54 GMT
ETag: "3be209000dbc7e1b95bcdf47980a3baa"
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 cec03b477881661a098cf57a0142e58d.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: NRT51-C2
X-Amz-Cf-Id: tuC_K1W4DW9QlEqV60T5WHbOCqvd5-ZAi7HeVNYW0mGCXxO9pKkpyQ==
Age: 44228

/var/folders/qz/072qbsw163lb8p511v4dtssr0000gq/T/ruby-build.20200304000500.19560.8ElfaA/openssl-1.1.1d /var/folders/qz/072qbsw163lb8p511v4dtssr0000gq/T/ruby-build.20200304000500.19560.8ElfaA ~/Documents/launch_school
Operating system: x86_64-apple-darwinDarwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Thu Jan 23 06:52:12 PST 2020; root:xnu-4903.278.25~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1d (0x1010104fL) for darwin64-x86_64-cc
Using os-specific seed configuration
Creating configdata.pm
Creating Makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************
WARNING! If you wish to build 32-bit libraries, then you have to
         invoke 'KERNEL_BITS=32 ./config  '--prefix=/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl' '--openssldir=/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl' 'zlib-dynamic' 'no-ssl3' 'shared''.
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.2/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
      "-oMakefile" crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h.in > crypto/include/internal/bn_conf.h
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.2/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
      "-oMakefile" crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h.in > crypto/include/internal/dso_conf.h
/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.2/bin/perl "-I." -Mconfigdata "util/dofile.pl" \
      "-oMakefile" include/openssl/opensslconf.h.in > include/openssl/opensslconf.h
make depend && make _all
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/app_rand.d.tmp -MT apps/app_rand.o -c -o apps/app_rand.o apps/app_rand.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/apps.d.tmp -MT apps/apps.o -c -o apps/apps.o apps/apps.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/bf_prefix.d.tmp -MT apps/bf_prefix.o -c -o apps/bf_prefix.o apps/bf_prefix.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/opt.d.tmp -MT apps/opt.o -c -o apps/opt.o apps/opt.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/s_cb.d.tmp -MT apps/s_cb.o -c -o apps/s_cb.o apps/s_cb.c
clang  -I. -Iinclude -fPIC -arch x86_64 -O3 -Wall -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/openssl/lib/engines-1.1\"" -D_REENTRANT -DZLIB -DZLIB_SHARED -DNDEBUG -I/Users/<username>/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/include -MMD -MF apps/s_socket.d.tmp -MT apps/s_socket.o -c -o apps/s_socket.o apps/s_socket.c
ar r apps/libapps.a apps/app_rand.o apps/apps.o apps/bf_prefix.o apps/opt.o apps/s_cb.o apps/s_socket.o
ar: creating archive apps/libapps.a
/usr/local/Cellar/cctools/855/bin/ranlib: object: apps/libapps.a(app_rand.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
ar: internal ranlib command failed
make[1]: *** [apps/libapps.a] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The steps I have taken so far are:

- Updated the `ruby-build` rbenv plugin which is required to install Ruby via rbenv.
- Installed the latest version of Xcode along with the latest version of its Command Line Tools as suggested in "[How to fix ranlib/libtool error when running make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263588/ranlib-libtool-error-when-running-make-command)".
- Uninstalled MacPorts as suggested in "[Arm64 problem while configure](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/issues/28)" by following "[Uninstall MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html)".

Note: [The initial question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493172/how-to-install-a-new-ruby-version-on-mac-os-with-build-problems) was closed due to it being labeled as "off-topic". I hope this one continues to stay open so people can provide and reference the solution(s) to the problem discussed above.

Comment: To close voters: Questions about how to install and use developer specific tools are on-topic for SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cannot install any version of ruby on Mojave - internal ranlib command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54363030/1380680)

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Good find.  Thanks!